# Batch SELECT ids in an array while preserving the array order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an array of ids that might repeats: `[1,4,2,1,4,6,7]`

Manually I have to do

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid='1'
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid='4'
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid='2'
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid='1'
.....
```

one by one and combine everything later

Is there a way to do it in a single query while preserving its order?
So I would get

```
| id |  props |
|----|--------|
| 1  | 1_props|
| 4  | 4_props|
| 2  | 2_props|
| 1  | 1_props|
```

Comment: Try to use IN 
SQL QUERY should be like  SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid IN ('1','4','2');

Answer (score 3):

You can unnest the array and then join against it. The option `with ordinality` will include the index of the element in the array as a column. That can be used to sort the result:

```
select p.*
from products p
  join unnest(array[1,4,2,1,4,6,7]) with ordinality as t(id, idx) on t.id = p.catid
order by t.idx;
```